# What is the difference between pulse-skipping mode and burst-mode in power converters?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I have been looking at methods to regulate a resonant converter which switches from full load to zero load at rates anywhere from 100Hz to 100kHz. I am looking online at some journal/conference papers and two methods seem to be the use of "burst-mode" and "pulse-skipping" to regulate the output voltage when there is little to no-load current.

What is the difference between these two? What are the advantages of one over the other, and when exactly is it best to use them, respectively?

EDIT: I am most interested in these techniques in a resonant converter design of mine which I am struggling to control at no load conditions after a load pulse transient occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard about "burst-mode". Pulse skipping is a simple method to limit the output voltage / current within the maximum permitted margins. The simplest analogy is a children swing. You push every cycle in resonance as long you have enough amplitude, then you skip pushing until the swing goes lower. In a resonance circuit there is a similar behaviour, if the load is small, the amplitudes grow higher and higher if you continue to pump the energy into a resonant tank.

EDIT:

A paper describing pulse skipping:

[Link](http://www.dgkelectronics.com/storage/electronics/induction_heater/Esteve_IH_enhanced_PDM_october.pdf)

Comment: So pulse skipping stops the amplitudes from growing higher and higher during low/no-load? Can it be used to regulate a resonance converter at no load?

Comment: @jvnlendm To regulate what, if there is no load?

Comment: If there is no load, the voltage still needs to be regulated, no?

Comment: @jvnlendm You didn't give any schematics or any useful detail about your converter. Further it is not clear how it changes the frequency so widely (100Hz to 100kHz), IMO that's not possible with resonating converters, it shall have a resonating tank with fixed frequency, else it can't be resonating converter.

Comment: I think maybe you have misunderstood. The resonant converter does not change its frequency within that range. The output load is pulsed ON and OFF at those frequencies (depending on the application chosen). I will update with a schematic soon.